# Reffering to a public string from another class?

Tags: c#, .net, windows

For some reason even though I have declared a string in Program.cs static and public, when I reference it in another class e.g. Class1.cs, it does not find it:

**Program.cs**

```
public static string fileName = "test.txt";
```

**Class1.cs**

```
    XElement address = new XElement("PingResults",
        new XElement("NameoFile", fileName),
        new XElement("URL", test),
        new XElement("Time", test2)
    );
```

I have also tried using Class1.fileName, but no luck.. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have defined `fileName` in the class `Program`. Therefore you should access it via `Program.fileName`.

Side note: `fileName` doesn't follow .NET naming standards. use `FileName` instead!

Comment: Hi Mathew, if you think this answer is the best, please consider accepting it by clicking the tick to the left :)

Answer (score 4):

In this case, you would use `Program.fileName` - because `fileName` is a field on the `Program` class.

It's important to note that this is not the best way - `public static` things are visible to all classes, however you would probably be better off passing a parameter to the method in `Class1` - e.g. `ProcessXml(fileName)` would be the method call, `public void ProcessXml(string fileName)` would be the method signature in `Class1`, then within the `ProcessXml` method, or whatever it is called, you have access to the parameter `fileName` and its value.

As Cicada implied, the naming is also off.  See here for some guidelines: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xzf533w0(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: Thank you, could you possibly elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

I think you could get it at Program.fileName, but this is a pretty bad way to go about this.

Comment: :tom.dietrich Hi, can you explain who so?

Comment: Kieren's answer is what I'd recommend.

Answer (score 0):

What class is `fileName` a static member of? Is it a member of class `Program`? In this case you need `Program.filename`

A ***static*** field `f` of a class `A` must be accessed with the following syntax:
`A.f`
A ***non-static*** field `f` of a class `A` must be accessed with `a.f` where a is an object(instance) of type `A`

Answer (score 0):

It'll be in whatever class is defined in Program.cs, probably Program.

Answer (score 0):

Static members used outside the class should be preceded by the name of the class in which they're declared. Try `Program.fileName`

Answer (score 0):

any static member belongs to a type. So you will have to tell the compile in which type to look for the member. There's no such thing as truely globals in C#.

Assumming that your class is called Program the line of code should be:

```
new XElement("NameoFile", Program.fileName),
```